# Flexbox filling not work after change browser window size in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, cross-browser, flexbox

I try to create a simple crossbrowser abaptive web design based on flexbox technology, but have problem in Chrome browser. Here is default view: [Flexbox crossbrowser design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihNMI.png)

If i minimize browser window and reduce the width of the window - content text from "flexContent" block is stretched down out from the browser window. In Chrome "flexSidebar" block calculated itself height wrong! In Firefox, Opera and IE height calculating for "flexSidebar" block is fine. Here you can see blue  background in minimized Chrome: [Blue  background below flexSidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwSBD.png)

CSS:

```
    html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;  
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

html{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: red;
}

.flexWrapper{
    flex-basis: 100%;
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: purple;
}

.flexHeader{
    flex-basis: 50px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    background-color: green;
}

.flexSidebar{
    flex-basis: 250px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    background-color: mediumvioletred;
}

.flexContent {
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.flexPage{
    flex-basis: 100%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    background-color: tomato;
}

.flexFooter {
    flex-basis: 50px;    
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    background-color: turquoise;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The FlexBox</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <link href="assets/main/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flexHeader">
            Flex Header
        </div>
        <div class="flexWrapper">
            <div class="flexSidebar">
                Flex Sidebar
            </div>
            <div class="flexContent">
                <div class="flexPage">
                    flexPage<br />
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div> 
                <div class="flexFooter">
                    Flex Footer
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure what your problem is. This seems to work fine in Chrome: http://codepen.io/jaycrisp/pen/dGQoLQ?editors=1000

Comment: Not sure that you can reproduce the problem on codepen. I share web site here: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/2bNDnJw2Gaz7/public_html.zip

Comment: JamieC, i reproduce problem on codepen. Try to minimize the browser window like i do: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4AbHBCfu6Yj9/Image%20123.png